# JavaScript create or update key in JSON object

Tags: javascript

I want to create JSON object using pure JavaScript as below:

```
{
  "0": {
     "0": {
          "key1": 1,
          "key2": 2
     },
     "1": {
          "key1": 1,
          "key2": 2
      }
  }
  "1": {
     "0": {
          "key1": 1,
          "key2": 2
      }
  }
}
```

But when I try below code I get error for undefined:

```
var myJosnObj = {};
myJosnObj["0"]["0"] = {"key1": 1,"key2": 2};
```

I am getting error:
`Error: myJosnObj[0] is undefined`

I want to either create or update the existing key in the json document.

Comment: Firstly, `myJosnObj["0"]` tries to grab the value at the key `"0"` in your `myJosnObj` (which doesn't exist, so you get `undefined`), and then the subsequent `["0"]` tries to set the key `"0"` on that value you just grabbed to the object to the right of the `=`. Since that value you grabbed doesn't exist/is undefined, so can't set the `"0"` key on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const myJosnObj = {};
myJosnObj["0"] = {}
myJosnObj["0"]["0"] = {"key1": 1,"key2": 2};
```

You need to define myJosnObj["0"]

Answer (score 1):

you can directly do :

```js
const myJosnObj = 
      { "0": 
        { "0": { "key1": 1, "key2": 2} 
        , "1": { "key1": 1, "key2": 2} 
        } 
      , "1": 
        { "0": { "key1": 1, "key2": 2} 
        } 
      }
```